# Extracting block of data from a file

Tags: awk

I have a problem, which surely can be solved with an awk one-liner.

I want to split an existing data file, which consists of blocks of data into separate files. 
The datafile has the following form:

```
1   1
1   2
1   3


2   1
2   2
2   3

3   1
3   2
3   3
```

And i want to store every single block of data in a separate file, named - for example - "1.dat", ".dat", "3.dat",...
The problem is, that each block doesn't have a specific line number, they are just delimited by two "new lines".

Thanks in advance,
Jürgen

Comment: See also [csplit](http://linux.die.net/man/1/csplit).

Answer (score 4):

This should get you started:

```
awk '{ print > ++i ".dat" }' RS= file.txt
```

If by two "new lines" you mean, two newline characters:

```
awk '{ print > ++i ".dat" }' RS="\n\n" file.txt
```

See how the results differ? Setting a null `RS` (i.e. the first example) is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
awk 'NF != 0 {print > $1 ".dat"}' file.txt
```